# How to handle buffer overflow in ndis driver

Tags: driver, ndis

How can I handle buffer overflow in ndis driver. Can anybody tell some buffer overflow scenarios or some use cases of buffer overflow conditions.

Comment: This question is too open-ended to get a useful answer.  Can you be more specific on what you're after?

Comment: Actually, I am talking about reg NDIS miniport driver buffer overflow conditions. Suppose any packet comes that more than max buffer size handled in miniport driver then how to handle that case ?

Answer (score 3):

### For NDIS miniport drivers

If you receive a packet that is larger than the MTU, discard it.  Do not indicate the packet up to NDIS (i.e., do not pass the packet to `NdisMIndicateReceiveNetBufferLists`).  If possible, increment the `ifInErrors` statistical counter.

The above rule is not affected by the `NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS` flag; do not indicate excessively-large packets even when in promiscuous mode.  However, you should indicate excessively-small (aka "runt") packets when in promiscuous mode, if your hardware permits it.

If you are asked to transmit a packet that is larger than the MTU, do not attempt to transmit it.  Assign `NET_BUFFER_LIST::Status = NDIS_STATUS_INVALID_LENGTH` and return the NBL back to NDIS with `NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete`.  (I wouldn't expect you to ever see such a packet; it would be a bug for NDIS to attempt to send you such a packet.)

### For NDIS protocol drivers

If you receive a packet that is larger than the MTU, you are free to discard it.

Never attempt to send a packet that is larger than the MTU.

### For NDIS filter drivers

If a filter receives a packet that is larger than the MTU (`FilterReceiveNetBufferLists`), the filter may immediately discard the packet (`NdisFReturnNetBufferLists` if the receive indication is not made with `NDIS_RECEIVE_FLAGS_RESOURCES`, or just returning immediately if the resources flag is set).

If a filter is asked to send a packet that is larger than the MTU (`FilterSendNetBufferLists`), the filter may assign `NET_BUFFER_LIST::Status = NDIS_STATUS_INVALID_LENGTH` and return the packet immediately (`NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete`).

Filters are not obligated to validate the size of *every* packet that passes through them.  However, your filter should validate the size of any packets where a malformed packet would otherwise cause your filter to trigger a buffer overflow.  For example, if your filter copies all ARP replies into a pre-allocated buffer, first validate that the ARP reply isn't too large to fit into the buffer.  (This is not strictly necessary, since the miniport "shouldn't" give you an excessively-large packet.  However, you *are* on the network datapath, which means you're handling untrusted data being processed by a potentially-buggy miniport.  A little extra defense-in-depth is a good idea.)

Filters must not originate packets that are larger than the MTU (on either the send or receive paths).